# On Windows, how can I send/read text messages from my phone?

Tags: sms, windows

Is there a convenient way of reading/sending text messages from my phone through Windows? I remember Nokia's Symbian phones had a piece of software to do just that, but I can't find any simple solutions for Android.

I'm using Android 5.1 on a Nexus 4.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using the web interface to do this, go get Airdroid.